# Trying to import old video from tape into iMovie 10.0.9, and store it on peripheral drive

Tags: hard-drive, folders, imovie, import

I can't control which file or folder to target. I can only name a target an event name, and then that event only shows in the iMovie libraries menu on the left. Cant find the even in Finder to copy it to hard drive.

Answer (score 1):

iMovie imports into events, which are stored wherever you have chosen. Once you've imported the media, you can right-click on an event and select Reveal in Finder to reveal its location and either move/copy the event or move/copy the media within.